# If the area under graph of $f$ is measurable then $f$ is measurable

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space and $f \colon X \to [0,\infty]$ such that
\begin{equation}
\{ (x,y) \in  X \times \mathbb{R} \colon 0<y<f(x) \}
\end{equation}
is measurable respect to $\mu \otimes \lambda$ where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.  How can I prove that $f$ is measurable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $E$ is a measurable set in $X \times \mathbb R$ then its sections are measurable. (This is part of Fubini's Theorem). Let $E$ be the graph of $f$. Fix $y$ consider the section $E^{y}\equiv \{x:(x,y)\in E\}$. This is nothing but $\{x: f(x) >y\}$. Hence $\{x: f(x) >y\}$ is measurable for each $y$ which proves that $f$ is measurable.

Comment: Let $\mu_1$ be the lebesgue measure on $[a,b]$ and $\mu_2$ the lebesgue measure on $\mathcal{R}^2$, does the result still hold if the graph is measurable w.r.t $\mu_2$?

Comment: @AlekFröhlich  Yes, it still holds.  See my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4241607/does-the-area-under-the-graph-being-lebesgue-measurable-imply-the-function-is-me?noredirect=1#comment8814669_4241607