# The function that generates a measurable graph is measurable

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions, measurable-sets

I have seen a lot of questions trying to show that graphs are measurable. However, I'm asking for the other direction. This is the question:

Suppose $(X, \mathcal{S})$ is a measurable space and $f : X \to [ 0, \infty ] $ is a function. Let $\mathcal{B}$ denote the σ-algebra of Borel subsets of $( 0, \infty )$. Prove that $U_f \in S \otimes \mathcal{B}$ if and only if $f$ is an $\mathcal{S}$-measurable function.

Definition of $U_f$:

Suppose $X$ is a set and $f : X \to [ 0, ∞ ]$ is a function. Then the region under the graph of $f$ , denoted $U_f$ , is defined by
$U_f = \{( x, t ) \in X \times ( 0, \infty ) : 0 < t < f ( x )\} $.

I'm only asking how to show the forward direction: if $U_f \in S \otimes \mathcal{B}$ then $f$ is an $\mathcal{S}$-measurable function.

Here $\mathcal{S} \otimes \mathcal{B}$ is defined as the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains $\{A \times B: A \in \mathcal{S}, B \in \mathcal{B} \}$.

I'm trying to show that $f^{-1}((a, \infty)) \in \mathcal{S}$, but I'm completely stuck. Can I get some help?

Comment: May we know the definition of $U_{f}$ in this context?

Comment: @RoycePacibe Sorry. Added the definition.

Comment: I think you'll find your answer here. It seems that you need to invoke Fubini's theorem to prove it. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2989108/if-the-area-under-graph-of-f-is-measurable-then-f-is-measurable

Comment: This is shown in [Edgar's book *Integral, Probability and Fractal Measures](https://books.google.be/books?id=ZrLVBwAAQBAJ), proposition 2.1.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mapping $$X \ni x \mapsto h(x):=(x,a) \in X \times (0,\infty)$$ is measurable for any fixed  $a>0$. Thus, $h^{-1}(U_f) \in \mathcal{S}$. Noting that $$h^{-1}(U_f) = \{x \in X; a<f(x)\}=f^{-1}((a,\infty)),$$ it follows that $f$ is measurable.