# $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is measurable iff $\{(x, t): t=f(x)\} \in \mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing, measurable-functions, product-measure

A function $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is measurable if and only if its graph is measurable, $\{(x, t): t=f(x)\} \in \mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

This is easy when we consider the points under the graph, but not sure how to do the graph itself

Comment: If it is indeed easy when we consider points under the graph, then it suffices to make the argument that your set can be written as 
$$
S = \{(x,t) : t \leq f(x)\} \setminus \{(x,t): t < f(x)\},
$$
and the difference of measurable sets is measurable.

Comment: It is also easy to prove that if $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is measurable, then $\{(x, t): t=f(x)\} \in \mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: It indeed seems that the "only if" direction is significantly trickier

Comment: @BenGrossmann I SUSPECT that the "only if" part, in the general case, is false. The results I know in this direction impose additional conditions on $X$ (for instance, that $X$ be a complete separable metric space). See, for instance, https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1974-044-01/S0002-9939-1974-0335728-X/S0002-9939-1974-0335728-X.pdf

Comment: @Xiao If we are given that the region under the graph is measurable, then we could apply [the argument given here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3729620/81360). Is this what you meant by "this is easy when we consider the points under the graph"?

Comment: @XiaoMem24 So that is what you meant. In any case, as the other commenter mentions, there is reason to believe that the a function might fail to be measurable even though its graph is measurable. Do you have any reason to believe that the "only if" that you're looking for is a true statement?

Comment: @XioMem24 What are two texts that say that the "only if" part holds in the general case? Please, could you give those references?

Comment: @XioMem24 In both texts you mentioned, it is a just proposed exercise.  As I said, I SUSPECT that the "only if" part, **in the general case**, is false. The results I know in this direction impose additional conditions on $X$ (for instance, that $X$ be a complete separable metric space). See, for instance, https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1974-044-01/S0002-9939-1974-0335728-X/S0002-9939-1974-0335728-X.pdf

Comment: @XiaoMen24 Exactly. It is advanced and it is a peer reviewed paper published by AMS (American Mathematics Society) in May 1974. The final result (proposition 6 of section 3) is the "only if" part under the assumption that $X$ is a complete separable metric space.  I don't believe AMS would accept to publish the paper, if the general case could be proved just as an exercise of product measure and iterate integral.

Answer (score 3):

It is also easy to prove that if $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is measurable, then $\{(x, t): t=f(x)\} \in \mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

Since  $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is measurable, we have that $g: X \times  \mathbb{R} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R} $  defined by $g(x,y)= y-f(x)$ is $\mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable.

So $g^{-1}(\{0\}) \in  \mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. But $g^{-1}(\{0\}) = \{(x, t): t=f(x)\}$.

So $\{(x, t): t=f(x)\} \in \mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.