# Does the area under the graph being lebesgue measurable imply the function is measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

The opposite implication is true, but i don't know about this side. I've considered intersecting the area under the graph of the function with subsets of the form $\mathbb{R} \times (a,\infty)$. This intersection has to be measurable, but it doesn't seem to follow that the x-coordinates of this set are also measurable (in $\mathbb{R}$). For example, the set $\mathcal{V} \times \{ 0 \}$, where $\mathcal{V}$ is a vitali set, is measurable on $\mathbb{R}^2$, but it's x-coordinates are not measurable on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/321922), for example.

Comment: He's using a nonconventional definition, i'm following the usual caratheodory definition for lebesgue measurability and inverse of (a,oo) is lebesgue measurable for function measurability. How would one show the implication by following those definitions?

Comment: Have you tried Fubini's theorem?

Comment: See  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2989108/if-the-area-under-graph-of-f-is-measurable-then-f-is-measurable .

This is a almost complete answer to your question. The only point you need to adjust is that the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra for $\Bbb R^2$ is NOT the product of the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra for $\Bbb R$. It is the completion of the product $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: @Ramiro I haven't studied fubini's theorem, this question is purely out of my curisity, but isn't the idea behind your link essentially what i did ( see the details i left in the question )? The main problem seems to be that it's not true anymore that the x-coordinates of a lebesgue measurable set are measurable, i don't know how to fix this or even if my question is true.

Comment: The idea is close to your but not exactly the same. You must consider the sections in area under the graph. "Let $E$ be the graph of $f$. Fix $y$ consider the section $E^{y}\equiv \{x:(x,y)\in E\}$. This is nothing but $\{x: f(x) >y\}$".

Comment: @Ramiro Honestly it's still not clear to me, the example i gave ( vitali x {0} ) is lebesgue measurable although it's section ( vitali ) is not. Your link's ideas dont seem to apply here

Comment: Your example (Vitali $x {0}$) is due to the fact that, as I wrote, the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra for $\Bbb R^2$ is NOT the product of the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra for $\Bbb R$. It is the completion of the product $\sigma$-algebra.  It is why I said the link I presented was an ALMOST complete answer.  The deals only with product $\sigma$-algebra, not its completion.

Comment: @d.k.o. well, based on the exchange of comments, i'm not sure if that's the way to go.

Comment: @Ramiro Well, i see, but, at least to me, it seems to require new ideas ( if it is even true afterall ).

Comment: The result is true. I posted a detailed answer.  It uses Fubini Theorem for the completion of product of $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: In fact, your example (Vitali $\times \{c\}$ can not happen when we consider the area under the graph.

Comment: @victormd: The function will be Lebesgue measurable, but not necessarily Borel measurable. By Lebesgue measurable I mean that on any integrable set $A\subset \mathbb{R}$, and $\varepsilon>0$, there is an integrable subset $A_0\subset A$ such that $\lambda(A\setminus A_0)<\varepsilon$, and on $A_0$ $f$ will be the uniform limit of step functions (or continuous functions). Lieb and Loss book Aanalys, AMS, constructs integration using that "layer-cake"  method described in the link you gave. The whole things, is equivalent to the integration a la Lebesgue-Caratheodory or a la Daniell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a little too long for a comment.

When considering in $\Bbb R^2$ the product of the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra for $\Bbb R$, the question is already answered by @Kavi Rama Murthy  here: [If the area under graph of $f$ is measurable then $f$ is measurable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2989108/if-the-area-under-graph-of-f-is-measurable-then-f-is-measurable) .

So the step that remains is due to the fact that the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra for $\Bbb R^2$ is NOT the product of the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra for $\Bbb R$. It is the completion of the product $\sigma$-algebra.

Let $f: \Bbb R \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ be a function. Let $E=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2:0 < y < f(x)\} $ and suppose that $E$ is Lebesgue measurable in $\Bbb R^2$.

For any $a \in [0, \infty]$, let us define the section $E^{a} = \{x:(x,a)\in E\}$. It is easy to see that $E^{a} = \{x:(x,a)\in E\}= \{x: f(x) >a\}$.

By Fubini Theorem for completion of product $\sigma$-algebras, we have that for almost all $a\in [0, \infty]$, $E^a$ is measurable. That means, there exist a set $N \subset [0, \infty]$, such that $\lambda(N) =0$ and for all $a \in [0, \infty] \setminus N$,
$E^a$ is measurable.

So it remains to prove that for all $a\in N$, we also have that $E^a$ is measurable.

Note that $E^{\infty} = \emptyset$ and it is measurable. So, we can assume, without loss of generality that  $N \subset [0, \infty)$,

Given $a \in N$. Then $0 \leq a < \infty$. Since $\lambda(N) =0$, given any $\varepsilon >0$, we have that $(a, a +\varepsilon) \nsubseteq N$. So, we can build a strictly decreasing sequence $(a_n)_n$ such that for all $n$, $a_n \in (a, \infty) \setminus N$ and $a_n \to a$.

So, for all $n$, $E^{a_n}$ is measurable and
$$E^{a} = \{x: f(x) >a\}= \bigcup_n \{x: f(x) >a_n\}  =\bigcup_n E^{a_n}$$
So $E^a$ is measurable.

So we have proved that for all $a \in [0, \infty]$ , $E^a$ is measurable. Since $E^{a} =\{x: f(x) >a\}$, we have that  for all $a \in [0, \infty]$, $\{x: f(x) >a\}$ is measurable, which means that $f$ is Lebesgue measurable.